# Generate Youtube Url Thumb Image On Page Load PHP

Tags: php

I Want To Generate a Youtube Thumb On Page Load Event From The value Given In the Textboxes(Array Of Textboxes).The Form Code Which Contains The TextBoxes With Value Is Given Below.Please Help Me In Solving This Problem.

```
<script language="javascript">
function getthumbonload()
    {
    var msg1 = document.getElementById('video_url[]').value;

    var str1 = msg1;
    var parts1 = str1.split("/");
    var tmp1 = parts1[parts1.length-1];
    somestr1 = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ tmp1+"/3.jpg?a="+Math.random();
    }
</script>
<form name="frmupdate" method="post" id="formID" action="videos_db.php" >
    <?php
    if ($totalRecords > 0) {
        $perColumn = 2;
        $colWidth = floor(100 / $perColumn);
        $Totalrows = ceil($totalRecords / $perColumn);
        ?>

        <body onload="getthumbonload();">
        <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tblbg">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="<?php echo $perColumn; ?>" valign="top" class="tblheader">Edit / Delete Videos<br />
                           </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $mainCnt = 1;
                    for ($rowCnt = 1; $rowCnt <= $Totalrows; $rowCnt++) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <?php for ($colCnt = 1; $colCnt <= $perColumn; $colCnt++) { ?>
                        <td width="<?php echo $colWidth; ?>%" valign="top" class="tblrow">
                    <?php
                    if ($mainCnt <= $totalRecords && mysql_data_seek($result, $mainCnt - 1) && $arow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center"><input name="video_id[]" type="checkbox" id="video_id[]" value="<?php echo $arow["video_id"]; ?>" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" class="tblrow">
                             <input type="label" class="input" name="title[]" value="<?php echo $arow["title"]; ?>" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" class="tblrow">
                            <input name="video_url[]" type="text" class="input videoURLTXT" id="video_url[]" value="<?php echo setDB($arow["video_url"], "display"); ?>" maxlength="100" /><input name="vid_id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $arow["video_id"]; ?>" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="tblrow"><img src="" id="videoThumb"></td>
                         </tr>

                    </table>

                    <?php }
                        else echo "&nbsp;"; ?>

                    </td>
                        <?php
                        $mainCnt++;
                        }
                        ?>      
                </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>      
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
         <br />
        <table width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td><input name="btnupdate" type="submit" class="but" id="btnupdate" value="Update All" />
                    &nbsp;
                    <input name="btndel" type="button" class="but" id="btndel" value="Delete Selected" onclick="setAction('delete');" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="myaction" value="update">
        <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<?php echo $cid; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="modelid" value="<?php echo $modelid; ?>" />



    <?php
}
else
    echo "<center class=\"tblrow1\">No Records found.</center>";

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</form>
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What's your problem? What does your code and what do you expect it should do instead? And what happens in this JS function `getthumbonload()`?

Comment: I want to generate Thumb Image From Youtube Url Which is there in <tr>
 <td align="center" class="tblrow">
 <input name="video_url[]" type="text" class="input videoURLTXT" id="video_url[]" value="<?php echo setDB($arow["video_url"], "display"); ?>" maxlength="100" /></td>
</tr> and The function getthumbonload i added to the code above  gets the url from the textbox and returns the url for generating youtube thumnb image

Comment: Well this `video_id[]` is not a valid ID. Name your ID attributes like `video-{counter++}`. And use `jQuery` to do your JS stuff instead if plain JS.